# CSS gradients in Fancybox jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, fancybox, gradient

I'm tweaking my fancybox jQuery so there'll be a background gradient once you open the lightbox. I'm not too good with jQuery but this is what fancybox provided me with in order to customize my background color:

```
$(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
helpers : {
    overlay : {
        css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So I replaced `'rgba(255,255,255,1)'` with `'-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #B7F9EE, #FAD19C) fixed;'` and it worked, but now I don't know how to go about adding the declarations for the other browsers. I tried doing this:

```
css : {
    'background' : '-moz-linear-gradient(top, #B7F9EE, #FAD19C) fixed',
    'background' : '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #B7F9EE, #FAD19C) fixed',
    'background' : '-ms-linear-gradient(top, #B7F9EE, #FAD19C) fixed'
        }
```

but it just seems to output the last declaration and ignore the ones before.

Comment: you can try adding your custom class with your gradient background

Comment: Try only one `background` with a comma separator, otherwise I'd do what rajesh said.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use fancybox `tpl` API option to set a new *class* to the fancybox `skin` like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        tpl: {
            wrap: '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin myGradient"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>'
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** I added the *class* `myGradient` to the container with *class* `fancybox-skin`. Then you can add a regular css declaration within your own css file like :

```
.myGradient {
    background :         linear-gradient(top, #B7F9EE, #FAD19C) fixed;
    background :    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #B7F9EE, #FAD19C) fixed;
    background : -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #B7F9EE, #FAD19C) fixed;
    background :     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #B7F9EE, #FAD19C) fixed;
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xeh9cxkh/)**

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I tried doing that but it didn't work, maybe because my lightboxes aren't inline, they're ajax. I'll change them to inline if I don't find another solution.